# Electronic attachments for physical mailing

Tags: web-apps, file-management, security, sharing, hyperlink

I have a requirement to send a letter to a physical mailing address.  I have some attachments (generally pdf) that I'd like to ensure the recipient of the physical mailing receives access to.

One option would be to use a standard file sharing service, plug the file link into a URL shortener and then print the shortened URL on the physical letter.  I'd prefer to avoid using QR codes for the link.

I'm wondering if there's any alternative to this that makes sense.  Maybe a file sharing service that creates a random user name and password for each upload, that would be a manageable character length for printing on the letter?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Or you could mail a cheap USB stick loaded with the attachments. Or a (micro) SD card

Comment: Thanks for the response!  We're currently including CD's with the mailing, which are slow and cumbersome to create.  USB drives would be faster to create, but our organization has security restrictions on the use of USB drives for the majority of our staff.

Comment: Then, have a dedicated, air gapped, n9n networked PC  to write the medium. The advantage of micro SD with SD adapter is that it fits in  a normal letter and is not as fragile as a CD

Comment: Or just use  https://bitly.com/

Comment: Does each,per mailing, username/password need to be different?  Say you have for example google drive, create a folder, **clients** eg, and within there a sub folder for each one.  Now add the clients gmail address with at least read permission to that folder.  Then each client gets 1 folder, and they never need to enter credentials you send them physically.  Now you letter read "document paymeApril17.pdf has been uploaded to your shared drive."  Obviously this works with Onedrive,dropbox, and etc.

Comment: How about FileNurse (http://filenurse.com). The "About Us" page states that files can be password protected. And it provides a shortened URL. It does however delete the file after 7 days.